# How do I hide interval on canvasjs charts?

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I have a canvasjs line chart with an X and Y axis.
In canvasjs the interval on the Y axis is calculated automatically, unless I specify.
How do I remove it? I do not want the interval lines showing.

Example:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Simple Line Chart"
    },
    axisY:{
        interval: 10 < I want to hide this
    },
    data: [{        
            type: "line",       
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 414 },
                { y: 510 }
            ]
        }]
    });
chart.render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide grids and ticks by setting [gridThickness](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/gridthickness/) and [tickLength](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/ticklength/) to 0 respectively. If you like to hide axis labels along with removing grids and tick, you can use [labelFormatter](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/label-formatter/). Below is the working code, which hides grids, ticks and labels over axisY:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Simple Line Chart"
    },
    axisY:{
      gridThickness: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      labelFormatter: function(e) {
        return "";
      }
    },
    data: [{        
            type: "line",       
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 414 },
                { y: 510 }
            ]
        }]
    });
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted, and thanks for linking through to further information.